# converting Json to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Json string which I am trying to convert dataframe in python. code sample below.

```
import json 
import pandas as pd  

data = '[[{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "amt", "formattedValue": "amt"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "-2716.5299999999997", "formattedValue": "-2,716.53"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "Crds", "formattedValue": "Crds"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "-45526.209999999999", "formattedValue": "-45,526.21"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "Dbts", "formattedValue": "Dbts"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "42809.679999999993", "formattedValue": "42,809.68"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "Count", "formattedValue": "Count"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "205", "formattedValue": "205.00"}],[{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "amt", "formattedValue": "amt"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "0", "formattedValue": "0.00"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "Crds", "formattedValue": "Crds"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "0", "formattedValue": "0.00"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "Dbts", "formattedValue": "Dbts"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "0", "formattedValue": "0.00"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "Count", "formattedValue": "Count"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "17", "formattedValue": "17.00"}]]'
data = json.loads(data)
note = []
# tableau has  extra space in columns so adding space here.
columnName = ['amt','Crds','Dbts','Count']
for x in data:
    tup = (x[0]['value'],x[3]['value'])
    note.append(tup) 
    
note = sorted(list(set(note))) 
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(note)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columnName, index=index) 
print (df)
```

This gives following output. In the output the columns are not populated also the row order is different from the json. (in json %null% comes after 5311 record).

|  |  | amt | Crds | Dbts | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure1 | %null% | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
|  | 5311 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

But I am trying to get the output as below. It has column values populated with numbers and also the rows are in exact order as it is in json. Any suggestion on how to achieve this? thanks.

|  |  | amt | Crds | Dbts | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure1 | 5311 | -2,716.53 | -45,526.21 | 42,809.68 | 205.00 |
|  | %null% | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 17 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

data = '[[{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "amt", "formattedValue": "amt"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "-2716.5299999999997", "formattedValue": "-2,716.53"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "Crds", "formattedValue": "Crds"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "-45526.209999999999", "formattedValue": "-45,526.21"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "Dbts", "formattedValue": "Dbts"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "42809.679999999993", "formattedValue": "42,809.68"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "true", "formattedValue": "In"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "Count", "formattedValue": "Count"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "5311", "formattedValue": "5311"}, {"value": "205", "formattedValue": "205.00"}],[{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "amt", "formattedValue": "amt"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "0", "formattedValue": "0.00"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "Crds", "formattedValue": "Crds"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "0", "formattedValue": "0.00"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "Dbts", "formattedValue": "Dbts"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "0", "formattedValue": "0.00"}], [{"value": "Measure1", "formattedValue": "Measure1"}, {"value": "false", "formattedValue": "Out"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "Count", "formattedValue": "Count"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "%null%", "formattedValue": "Null"}, {"value": "17", "formattedValue": "17.00"}]]'
data = json.loads(data)

all_data = []
for _, subl in groupby(data, key=lambda k: (k[0]["value"], k[2]["value"])):
    subl = list(subl)
    out = {"lvl_0": subl[0][0]["value"], "lvl_1": subl[0][2]["value"]}
    for v in subl:
        out[v[4]["value"]] = v[-1]["formattedValue"]
    all_data.append(out)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data).set_index(["lvl_0", "lvl_1"])
df.index.names = [None, None]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       amt        Crds       Dbts   Count
Measure1 5311    -2,716.53  -45,526.21  42,809.68  205.00
         %null%       0.00        0.00       0.00   17.00
```

Comment: It worked for my requirement. Thank you very much!!